# What does the "store_" method do in Rails 4?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, callback, ruby-on-rails-6

I’m upgrading an app from Rails 4.2 to Rails 6.  One of the models has this

```
class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
    …
  skip_callback :save, :before, :store_document!, if: :skip_processing?
```

When upgrading to 6, the “:store_document!” throws an error “”, which was not thrown in the older Rails version.  “store_document” is not a method I have defined anywhere, so I’m assuming this is some kind of Rails shorthand for something.  My question is what does the “store_xxx!” Do and how can I reproduce that in Rails 6?

Comment: I think filling in "…" might benefit this question greatly

Answer (score 0):

this is the [store accessor](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/main/activerecord/lib/active_record/store.rb) in Active Record

the usage of which is described [here](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Store.html)

Looks like the arguments for it changed in Rails 6 to

```
store_accessor(store_attribute, *keys, prefix: nil, suffix: nil)
```

so my bet is you have a

```
store :document
```

statement somewhere that needs to be updated to the proper syntax.

Comment: In as far as I wasn't passing any arguments to "store_document!" when I was in Rails 4, I'm not clear how to fill in the attributes in the Rails 6 paradigm.

Comment: do you have something that looks like this? `store :document`